# No results from SQL Query

Tags: mysql, count, range

I am trying to count the number of nights guests stay within a range. So less than 7 nights, between 7 and 14 nights and lastly more than 14 nights.

I would like the output to look something like this:

```
Range         | Count
----------------------
<= 7 Nights   | 3
8 - 14 Nights | 2
15 Nights +   | 1
```

I am using MYSQL and have attempted the following two solutions, but no results seem to ever appear.

```
SELECT  
CASE
     WHEN booking_num_nights <= 7 THEN '<= 7 Nights'
     WHEN booking_num_nights > 7 and booking_num_nights <= 14 THEN '8 - 14 Nights'
     WHEN booking_num_nights > 14 THEN '15 Nights +'
  END AS range, count(*) AS count_num
FROM BOOKING
    WHERE booking_property_id = :id
    GROUP BY range
```

The other attempt was as follows:

```
SELECT booking_num_nights as range, count(*) as count_num
FROM (SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN booking_num_nights <= 7 THEN '<= 7 Nights'
        WHEN booking_num_nights > 7 and booking_num_nights <= 14 THEN '8 - 14 Nights'
        WHEN booking_num_nights > 14 THEN '15 Nights +'
    END AS range
 FROM BOOKING) 
WHERE booking_property_id = :id
GROUP BY range
```

Comment: *"but no results seem to ever appear"* - This description is very vague. Do you get empty results, or an error perhaps? If so, please gather the error information. For the other attempt, you didn't even describe the outcome at all. Also, table struction and example data will help, as well as the value you used for the input variable `:id`.

Comment: I am printing it out to JSON and when I output it to the error_log I see my column names, but no data at all for either of the two attempts.

Comment: If there is no error, but also no data, the problem cannot be in the case, or group by. It is the where clause that filters rows. The where clause is very simple, so the only reason can be that you either didn't specify a good value for `:id` at all, or did specify a value that doesn't match any `booking_property_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). Either use a different name or escape it:

```
SELECT  
    CASE
        WHEN booking_num_nights <= 7 THEN '<= 7 Nights'
        WHEN booking_num_nights > 7 and booking_num_nights <= 14 THEN '8 - 14 Nights'
        WHEN booking_num_nights > 14 THEN '15 Nights +'
    END AS `range`, count(*) AS count_num
FROM BOOKING
WHERE booking_property_id = :id
GROUP BY `range`
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15d80/3)

Comment: Thanks so much!  Can't believe I didn't realise that. Works perfectly.

Comment: You should have gotten a syntax error from the query. Make sure you have `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` set. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php